# Selenium Chrome Webdriver stalls when trying to get_attribute('href')

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I'm building a webcrawler using Selenium Webdriver with Chrome. It uses

```
links = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@href]")
```

gets all the links on a page and then loops through the links to filter them. However, on every site I've tested, once it gets to a certain link on a certain page, it stalls at this line:

```
url = link.get_attribute("href")
```

It's not an error, it just stops, as if it hit an unending loop. For a given site, it's always on the same link on the same page for every test run. The stalling does not occur with Firefox - everything works fine. However, I need it to do this using Chrome for other reasons (trust me on this).

The version of Chrome I'm using is 28.0.1500.52, and I'm using the latest Chrome driver, which is compatible with that version. What could be going on here?

**EDIT (IGNORE THIS EDIT)**

After looking into it some more, I've found what's causing the problem: There's a part further down in the code that mouses over every link that's found.

```
hov = ActionChains(self.browser).move_to_element(link)
hov.perform()
```

When I comment that part out, it works. Now I have to figure out why this should have any effect on getting the href attribute from a Selenium  link object (especially when it works fine for the first arbitrary number of link objects)...

**EDIT 2**

Ignore the first edit.

Comment: Wow. Could you possibly give us an example of such a link so we (I) could debug it and see?

Comment: I'm wondering why you are not just doing `.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")` or even `.find_elements_by_xpath("//a")`

Comment: When the browser is stalled and nothing seems to do anything, try to open up Chrome's JavaScript Console and see whether there is any Error. Also, what type of filtering are you performing on the links? Would it be simply possible to select those you want via an XPath expression?